# Compare columns from 2 different tables with only last inserted values in table_2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have two different tables in a SQL Server 2019 database as follows:

Table1

```
|id   | name   |
+-----+--------+
| 1   | rose   |
| 2   | peter  |
| 3   | ann    |
| 4   | rose   |
| 5   | ann    |
```

Table2

```
 | name2  |
 +--------+
 |rose    |
 |ann     |
```

I would like to retrieve only the last tow ids from table1 (which in this case 4 and 5) that match name2 in table2. In other words, match happens only once on the last added names in table1, furthermore, the ids (4, 5) to be inserted in table2.

How to do that using SQL?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Larnu for reply, I updated the question. if you notice there are more than 2 matches in table1, so it will retrieve not only 2 ids with JOIN

Comment: I tried your sentence but it brings back four ids because there are four matchs in talble2 @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu sorry i mean there are four matchs in talble1

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing:

```
select . . . -- whatever columns you want
from (select top (2) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      order by t1.id desc
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name2 = t1.name;
```

This doesn't seem particularly useful for the data you have provided, but it does what you describe.

EDIT:

If you want only the most recent rows that match, use `row_number()`:

```
select . . . -- whatever columns you want
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name2 = t1.name and t1.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: but the last added matches in table1 may also be not on the top (select top (2)) @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Adam . . . That makes more sense, but is definitely not how I read your question originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select name,id from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by t.name order by id desc) as rn
 from table1 t join table2 t1 on t.name=t1.name2
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so there could be many answers here. My first thought is that you simply want an inner join. This will fetch ONLY the data that both tables share.

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.name = Table2.name2
```

Comment: Yes this will fetch only the data that both tables share which is four different ids from table1. what i need is to fetch only the last added 2 matchs to table1, NOT ALL matches

Comment: "only the last added 2 matchs" - Then is there a date column that can determine which is the latest? Without that, I don't know how you expect to accomplish that output.